# Index multiple MongoDB fields, make only one unique

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, database

I've got a MongoDB database of metadata for about 300,000 photos. Each has a native unique ID that needs to be unique to protect against duplication insertions. It also has a time stamp.

I frequently need to run aggregate queries to see how many photos I have for each day, so I also have a `date` field in the format YYYY-MM-DD. This is obviously not unique.

Right now I only have an index on the `id` property, like so (using the Node driver):

```
collection.ensureIndex(
   { id:1 }, 
   { unique:true, dropDups: true }, 
   function(err, indexName) { /* etc etc */ }
);
```

The group query for getting the photos by date takes quite a long time, as one can imagine:

```
collection.group(
        { date: 1 },
        {},
        { count: 0 },
        function ( curr, result ) { 
            result.count++;
        },
        function(err, grouped) { /* etc etc */ }
);
```

I've read through the indexing strategy, and I think I need to also index the `date` property. But I don't want to make it unique, of course (though I suppose it's fine to make it unique in combine with the unique id). Should I do a regular compound index, or can I chain the `.ensureIndex()` function and only specify uniqueness for the `id` field?

Comment: You can have more than one index on a collection. The query engine can only use one index in one query, but you can have one index ensuring a unique key and another, on your date field, to speed up your query or aggregation by date

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Do I chain the .ensureIndex() call or do I do a compound index like { id: 1, date: 1 } ?

Comment: Just make two indices, because you want them to do two unrelated things. One is to ensure uniqueness of one field, the other to rapidly sort by another field. There is no good way to combine both requirements in one index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not have "mixed" type indexes which can be partially unique. On the other hand why don't you use `_id` instead of your `id` field if possible. It's already indexed and unique by definition so it will prevent you from inserting duplicates.

Mongo can only use a single index in a query clause - important to consider when creating indexes. For this particular query and requirements I would suggest to have a separate unique index on id field which you would get if you use `_id`. Additionally, you can create a non-unique index on date field only. If you run query like this:

```
db.collection.find({"date": "01/02/2013"}).count();
```

Mongo will be able to use index only to answer the query (covered index query) which is the best performance you can get.

Note that Mongo won't be able to use compound index on (id, date) if you are searching by date only. You query has to match index prefix first, i.e. if you search by id then (id, date) index can be used.

Comment: Your example `db.collection.find({date: ...})` isn't [a covered query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries). A covered query is one where all the fields in the query are part of index *and* the fields in the result are also in the same index. If you only have an index on `date`, a covered query would look like: `db.collection.find({date: ... }, {date:1, _id:0})`. You can check the [`indexOnly`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.indexOnly) value of an `explain()` to confirm.

Comment: @Stennie Mongo documentation is vague on this point. I assume that the best way to execute `count` would be to check if condition portion of a query can be covered by index. I hope MongoDB does it, and if it does not do it yet perhaps it will - I hope. I'm aware of this bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3493. So I can't really execute explain on count because it's not a cursor. They say explain on query with count removed would IN GENERAL give the same results. There is no definite answer here. I'd like to know if covered query is guaranteed in this case because in my mind it has to

Comment: @Stennie would you say that `db.collection.find({date: ...}).count()` is not covered and `db.collection.find({date: ... }, {date:1, _id:0})` is? In that case you can probably safely say that due to syntax differences here the first one is slower than the second. It's reasonable to expect that both queries would be identical since all fields must be thrown away due to count operation. I think if that's the case it's just a temporary imperfection. Would you be able to provide more official information on this?

Comment: I'd like to verify this point about covered query, but in either case the main point is that either executing a slightly modified version of this query or that same query should not case collection scan and should use an index solely.

Comment: Good question on whether `count()` can be expected to be covered or not ... I was thinking of the `find()` and may have commented before fully digesting :).  I agree that `count` *should* allow a covered query, but will confirm so the docs can be clarified as well.

Comment: Confirmed: `count()` always uses index only, if it can.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to pre aggregate in the schema itself. Whenever you insert a photo you can increment this counter. This way you don't need to run any aggregation jobs. You can also run some tests to determine if this approach is more performant than aggregation.